# How to zoom into user current location?

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I wanna zoom into the user current location when the app starts in the MapKit.
This is my code (in the viewDidLoad function):

```
Locate=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
Locate.delegate=self;
Locate.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
Locate.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[Locate startUpdatingLocation];
[super viewDidLoad];

//Region
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude=Locate.location.coordinate.latitude;
center.longitude=Locate.location.coordinate.longitude;

//Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.3f;
span.longitudeDelta=0.3f;
//Set Region
myRegion.center=center;
myRegion.span=span;
[_MyMap setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
```

Also I implemented the `didUpdateLocation` function with the same code as previous.
The problem is that when the user location is changing (when the user is moving) the screen makes zoom at him but I can't move the screen, if I try to move it return to the user location immediately, so I can't see the whole map.

Comment: in the `–locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method, after you have the location, try to `stopUpdatingLocation`, or avoid to run the zoom procedure every time when you get a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding touchesMoved function and I stopped updating the Location in this function.
Solved.

Answer (score 3):

For Zooming the map you have to change the region values means center and span.once see this one [Mapview Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222308/zoom-mapview-to-a-region-where-pins-are-dropped)

in my case i have used this one for moving the map when i click on particular button.

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(30.5982f,0.0001f);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {36, 90};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};
        MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
        [self.mapView setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];
```

Comment: The app zooms perfectly, but the problem is that I can't move the map anywhere except from the current user location. When I try to move the map, immediately it goes back the user current location.