# iOS map showing a user's current locaiton

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, currentlocation

I've been trying to get the user's current location to show up on my map, but haven't been able to. I'm new to MapKit so I'm probably missing something.

I do get the pop up alert asking for permission to use my current location, but then no location is actually shown.

Here's the code:

Header .h:

```
@interface TeachersMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,  CLLocationManagerDelegate>

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


@end
```

Implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
#endif

    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self
                                forKeyPath:@"location"
                                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                                   context:NULL];    

}
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: On MapView you need to set showUserCurrentLocation property to YES.

mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the user location by this:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

if you are using simulator, it won't show you your current location, it can be in USA. " Simulator by default you it will show some location in USA. If you want to change that location, in iOS Simulator menu, go to `Debug -> Location -> Custom Location`. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly. This works with `mapkit` and also with `CLLocationManager`"

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, though its zoomed out, is there a quick instruction to zoom the view into the area around the users location please?

Comment: you mean you want to Zoom the user location area right ?

Comment: well,you get can the zoom from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15833566/3800154 have a look