# How to fix CLLocation Manager from failing with location error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation, mkuserlocation

I am trying to make the CLLocation manager work but it keeps giving me an error message saying `locationManager failed with error=Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"`. I looked on stackoverflow for answers and I found that `This error also occurs if you have Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation checked but don't have a default location set.` Applying this, it brought up the blue dot with a set default location. But I want the current location of the user. I have the code for it, but doesn't seem to be working properly hence the error locating the current user.

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>
#import "Park.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
//@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refresh;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *parks;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MKUserLocation *userLocation;

-(void)startUpdating; //start location manager updating plus..
-(void)stopUpdating; //stop location manager updating plus..
-(IBAction)refresh; //call startUpdating

// Source: http://www.devfright.com/mkmapview-and-mkmapview-delegate-tutorial/
-(IBAction)setMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize locationManager, userLocation;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegateMethods

// This delegate method is called once for every annotation that is created.
// If no view is returned by this method, then only the default pin is seen by the user
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *view = nil;
    if(annotation != mv.userLocation)
    {

    // if it's NOT the user's current location pin, create the annotation
    Park *parkAnnotation = annotation;
    // Look for an existing view to reuse
    view = [mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"parkAnnotation"];

    // If an existing view is not found, create a new one
    if(view == nil)
    {
        view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:(id)parkAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"parkAnnotation"];
    }

    // Now we have a view for the annotation, so let's set some properties
    [(MKPinAnnotationView *)view setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
    [(MKPinAnnotationView *)view setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    [view setCanShowCallout:YES];

    // Now create buttons for the annotation view
    // The "tag" properties are set so that we can identify which button was tapped later
    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    leftButton.tag = 0;
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    rightButton.tag = 1;

    // Add buttons to annotation view
    [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:leftButton];
    [view setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

}
// send this annotation view back to MKMapView so it can add it to the pin
return view;
```

}

```
// This method is called when one of the two buttons added to the annotation view is tapped
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
Park *parkAnnotation = (Park *)[view annotation];
switch([control tag])
{
    case 0: // left button
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:parkAnnotation.link];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    break;

    case 1: // right button
    {
        //build maps url. This will launch the Maps app on the hardware, and the apple maps in the simulator
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = locationManager.location.coordinate;
        NSString *url2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,parkAnnotation.gps_location.coordinate.latitude,parkAnnotation.gps_location.coordinate.longitude];

                          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url2]];
    }
    break;

    default: NSLog(@"Should not be here in calloutAccessoryControlTapped, tag=%d!",[control tag]);
    break;
}
// Reference
// https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 20000,20000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
//add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"My Current Location";
point.subtitle = @"You are here.";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
[self stopUpdating];
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate animated:YES]; // animate current location when moving

// zoom onto the user's current location
float spanX = 0.00725;
float spanY = 0.00725;
//MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;

}

// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222308/zoom-mapview-to-a-region-where-pins-are-dropped
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView insideArray:(NSArray*)anAnnotationArray
{
// NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
if([mapView.annotations count] == 0) return;

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for(MKPointAnnotation *annotation in anAnnotationArray)
{
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides

region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"locationManager failed with error=%@",error);
[self stopUpdating];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Location Manager Failed!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Map and Location Initialization
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard; // set default selection
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[self startUpdating];

for(Park *park in self.parks)
{
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:(id)park];
}


} 

-(void)startUpdating //start location manager updating plus..
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)stopUpdating //stop location manager updating plus..
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
-(IBAction)refresh //call startUpdating
{
    [self startUpdating];
}

// Source: http://www.devfright.com/mkmapview-and-mkmapview-delegate-tutorial/
// Switch between map view type
-(IBAction)setMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
   switch(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
   {
    case 0: self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        break;
    case 1: self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        break;
    case 2: self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you running on an ios8 device?  If so then you must request additional authorisation to use core location

Comment: @Paulw11 And how do I do that? I'm not sure what you mean? Yes, I'm using an iOS device 8.0.2 and XCode 5.1.1, but that problem is a separate matter, I just want the location manager to work in the simulator first.

Comment: If you are using the ios7 simulator then it isn't the authorization problem - but you will need to address that - there are plenty of questions/answers on it here. I don't know what you mean by "the current location of the user" - on the simulator you have to simulate the users location via the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, one do you have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescriptionadded to your apps info.plist file? Two have you set a location in the simulator? (Debug->Location). Third one you must request additional authorisation to use core location in ios8.

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```